# Matplotlib violinplots overlap on the same column

Tags: python, matplotlib, violin-plot

I want to create a figure with different violin plots on the same graph (but not on the same column).
My data are a list of dataframes and I want to create a violin plot of one column for each dataframe. (the names of the columns in the final figure I prefer to have as a name that is inside each dataframe in one other column).

I used this code:

```
for i in range(0,len(sta_list)):
    plt.violinplot(sta_list[i]['diff_APS_1'])
```

I know that this is wrong, I want to split up the resulting plots in the figure.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the x-position of the violin plot for each column using `positions` argument

```
for i in range(0, len(sta_list)):
    plt.violinplot(sta_list[i]['diff_APS_1'], positions=[i])
```

A sample answer for demonstration taking the dataset from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43346806/4932316) post

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


x = np.random.poisson(lam =3, size=100)
y = np.random.choice(["S{}".format(i+1) for i in range(4)], size=len(x))
df = pd.DataFrame({"Scenario":y, "LMP":x})

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for i, key in enumerate(['S1', 'S2', 'S3', 'S4']):
    ax.violinplot(df[df.Scenario == key]["LMP"].values, positions=[i])
```

[image]